# How to connect new Mix Node(blender 3.4+) to other nodes via script

Tags: python, blender, bpy

Blender 3.4 introduced new combined Mix node. Which combines float, vector and color operation together in one node. Previously for mixRGB node you could connect input socket [1] for color1 input.

```
mix_RGB_node = mat.node_tree.nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeMixRGB') #create a new mixRGB node
texture_node = mat.node_tree.nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeTexImage') #create a new Texture node
mat.node_tree.links.new(texture_node.outputs['Color'], mix_RGB_node.inputs[1]) #connect the texture nodes color output to the mix nodes color1 input
```

But doing this for new Mix node doesn't work.

Tried to do this, but this doesnt work. Same as for output socket[0] doesn't work either.

```
mix_RGB_node = mat.node_tree.nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeMix') #create a new mixRGB node
mix_RGB_node.data_type = 'RGBA'
texture_node = mat.node_tree.nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeTexImage') #create a new Texture node
mat.node_tree.links.new(texture_node.outputs['Color'], mix_RGB_node.inputs[1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for color, the new Mix nodes input sockets are [6][7], and for color output it's [2] other nodes are used by other modes(float,vector)

so the right code will be

```
mat.node_tree.links.new(texture_node.outputs['Color'], mix_RGB_node.inputs[6]) #this connects with inputA
mat.node_tree.links.new(principled_node.inputs['Base Color'],mix_RGB_node.outputs[2] ) #this connects mix output to the base color of Principle bsdf
```